# Get user from ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-admin

Can someone please tell me the best way to get the users profile from a ForeignKey field?

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

{{ object.author }} just gives me the username but I want the entire users profile.

Also, is there a way to change the way the user is displayed in the admin field? I'd like it so you can chose the author based on their First Name & Last Name... at the moment the list just lists the users username.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using `{{ object.author }}` actually calls the `__unicode__` method on that object (which actually displays username). You will have to create your own view to display the user profile on a separate page or you can use `{{ object.author.first_name }}` etc to display all fields.

Eventually you will have to override the default user `__unicode__` method if you want something else in the admin fields as well.

Or you can see this documentation page: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: @hanpan: Could you please provide me some feedback on this suggestion? I'm interested to know if it fits your needs.